# Is it possible to transform a 4-column list into a 4-column table in NetLogo 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I have a code that generates an output in list form as below:

[image]

I would like the output to look like this:

[image]

is it possible to do this in netlogo 6.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *but*- I think your approach may be overcomplicating what you are after. As an alternative, consider something like this toy model:

```
extensions [ csv ]
turtles-own [ my_xcor my_ycor ]
globals [ output_list ]

to setup
  ca
  set output_list [["who" "my_xcor" "my_ycor" "tick"]]
  crt 2
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  ask turtles [
    rt random 90 - 45
    fd 1
    set my_xcor pxcor
    set my_ycor pycor
    set output_list lput ( list who my_xcor my_ycor ticks ) output_list
  ]
  tick
end

to example-experiment 
  setup
  repeat 5 [ go ]
  csv:to-file "example_output.csv" output_list
end
```

If you run the `example-experiment` procedure, it will export a file that looks something like:

[image]

---

If you **must** go this other route, and you can't parse your original csv output in something like R instead, which would potentially be simpler, consider this different setup:

```
extensions [csv]

globals [ output-list ]

turtles-own [ xcor-list ycor-list tick-list]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  set output-list [["who" "my_xcor" "my_ycor" "tick"]]
  crt 2 [
    set xcor-list []
    set ycor-list []
    set tick-list []
  ]
  repeat 5 [
    ask turtles [
      rt random 90 - 45
      fd 1
      set xcor-list lput pxcor xcor-list
      set ycor-list lput pycor ycor-list
      set tick-list lput ticks tick-list
    ]
  ]
end
```

Now, the idea is to loop over the turtles and collapse each of their tracking lists into a list of lists before exporting:

```
to export-long 
  ; Iterate over each turtle to extract their listed values
  foreach sort turtles [
    t ->
    ; Pull values / lists from each turtle in order
    let cur-x-list [xcor-list] of t
    let cur-y-list [ycor-list] of t
    let cur-tick-list [tick-list] of t
    let cur-who-list n-values ( length cur-x-list ) [[who] of t]
    
    ( foreach cur-who-list cur-x-list cur-y-list cur-tick-list  [
      [ a b c d ] ->
      let to-append ( list a b c d )
      set output-list lput to-append output-list
    ]) 
  ]
  
  ; Export the list to csv
  csv:to-file "list_example_output.csv" output-list
end
```

Result:

[image]